# How to wrap each object of a Collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections, wrapper

I have a class `Foo` for which I made an equivalence wrapper class `WrappedFoo` to change its `equals()` contract in some parts of the program.

I need to convert from `Foo` objects to `WrappedFoo` objects and vice versa in many places. But I also need to convert `Collection`s of `Foo`s and `WrappedFoo` from one to another. Is there any way I can achieve this in a generic way?

Basically I want a method that like this:

```
public static Collection<WrappedFoo> wrapCollection(Collection<Foo> collection)
```

The problem is that I don't know what kind of `Collection` implementation will be used and I wish to keep the same implementation for the resulting `Collection`.

Comment: NB: `Collection` is an `interface` and therefore has `implementation(s)`, not "subclasses".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Reflection API, you could do something like this (notice the `0` in the method name):

```
public static Collection<WrapperFoo> wrapCollection0(Collection<Foo> src)
{
    try
    {
        Class<? extends Collection> clazz = src.getClass();
        Collection dst = clazz.newInstance();
        for (Foo foo : src)
        {
            dst.add(new WrapperFoo(foo));
        }
        return dst;
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now implement a whole bunch one-liner overload methods using the method above (notice the `0` in the calls):

```
public static ArrayList<WrapperFoo> wrapCollection(ArrayList<Foo> src)
{
    return (ArrayList<WrapperFoo>) wrapCollection0(src);
}

public static Vector<WrapperFoo> wrapCollection(Vector<Foo> src)
{
    return (Vector<WrapperFoo>) wrapCollection0(src);
}

...
```

Comment: This is basically the two solutions I had came up with but they are both non-ideal: I prefer not to have to write a bunch of similar methods and I prefer to avoid using reflection. I wanted to see if there was a neater solution. I will accept this answer if no one finds a better solution.

Comment: Actually reflection isn't that bad. Try both methods at the same time. Hold on, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yea, it's true that it's not that bad and seems the best solution for now. It would break if a particular Collection implementation doesn't have a no args constructor, but I guess that's pretty rare.

Answer (score 2):

The Collection-Interface guarantees the existence of the "boolean addAll(Collection c)"-method.
I'd just try something along theese lines:

```java
public static Collection<WrappedFoo> wrapFoos(Collection<Foo> col) {
  Class<?> colClass = col.getClass();
  Collection<WappedFoo> newCol = colClass.getConstructor().getInstance();
  newCol.addAll(col);
  return newCol;
}
```

Comment: I can't `addAll()` since `WrappedFoo` is not extending `Foo`. However but doing a loop and adding each of them and calling the method that wraps `Foo` into `WrappedFoo` it should work. And then that matches @Martijn Courteaux's answer. It's just that I wanted to avoid using reflection.

Comment: You are right, the wrapping needs to be done explicitly. However I think you won't get around reflections to the point where you can instantiate the collection without coming from the original collections class, since you wanted to keep the original collection-implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Collections2.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) from the Google Guava libraries might provide the functionality you are looking for.

You should be able to pass a Function that wraps the Foo elements in WrappedFoo. The main question is whether it is acceptable for the new collection to be a view of the original collection (hence it will not have the same implementation as the original collection).

Comment: transform() return a generic `Collection<T>` not the concrete collection type. My understanding of OP's requirement is, pass in a `List<Foo>` get a `List<WrapperFoo>`

Comment: @Kent I think my answer is appropriate as this method matches his method signature. I did qualify my answer by mentioning that it returns a view collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since this question was asked, but since java 1.8 you can use streams to achieve that:

```
public static Collection<WrappedFoo> wrapCollection(Collection<Foo> collection) {
    List<WrappedFoo> wrappedList = collection.stream().map(m -> new WrappedFoo(m)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ApiBulkResponse<Wrapper>(wrappedList);
}
```

You'll just need to supply a constructor in your `WrappedFoo` class to transform or encapsulate your `Foo` object into a `WrappedFoo`.

Comment: I don't think this preserves the particular incoming Collection as the OP wanted.